# Angular checkboxes for objects within array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array, that contains objects. Each object has a boolean varaible (array[i].check). I want to make a table using AngluarJS that by clicking on a checkbox it directly change a boolean value of a specific object within my array.I use:

```
 <table> 
    <tr  data-ng-repeat="a in array">
            <td style="width:200px;"> {{a.name}}</td>   
            <td><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="a.check"  ng-checked="a.check"></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

But the value of every boolean remains false always. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the value of `a.check` a Boolean or a String?  In other words if you look at the actual value is it `false` or `"false"`?

Comment: Additionally, you shouldn't mix `ngModel` and `ngChecked`.  See the docs: [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

Comment: a.check is boolean, as received from REST server as boolean

Comment: Then try only using `ngModel` instead of both.

Comment: nope still no effect...I have tried just `ng-checked` and `ng-model` separately

Comment: can you show a [mcve] of your issue?  I was unable to reproduce your problem:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ztYLQU41WASL4Wza7mx5?p=preview.  For example, what does your `array` look like, **exactly**?  and what version of angular are you trying to use?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/VP0Pib9l28EErHBFx9fi?p=preview Idea is smth like this, I just want to keep thinbgs simplier as my array is much bigger (/*
 AngularJS v1.6.4)

Comment: using just `ngModel` worked! @zero298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this method of using `ng-model` alone, I have created a fiddle with the working method, apply this code, then share back with the issue and I will resolve it for you!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
 $scope.array = [{id:1, name: "test1", changeThisValue: false},{id:2, name: "test2", changeThisValue: true},{id:3, name: "test3", changeThisValue: true},{id:4, name: "test4", changeThisValue: true},{id:5, name: "test5", changeThisValue: true}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="a in array">
      <td style="width:200px;"> {{a.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a.changeThisValue">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <pre style="width:100px;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{array}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: using just `ngModel` worked! the first time i have tried I made a mistake that didn't noticed.....

Comment: @AlexP Glad you fixed it!